# How to share post in Facebook using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I have 5 divs in my program and in each div, it contains different content and share on FB button. Now when I click on this button, I need to share that particular content on FB. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 ways. Below links may help you. I am using code from this article.

1) Using javascript:

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

2) Graph API

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: These links are not working , redirecting to website home page

Answer (score 1):

FB php SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

This is full FB documentation for their PHP API.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <?php
                    $title=urlencode('Dressfinity');
                    $url=urlencode('http://www.facebook.com/pages/Dressfinity-LLC/208406062583392 ');
                    $image=urlencode('http://livemarketnews.com/dressfinity/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo.jpg');
                ?>
                <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
                    Share our Facebook page!
                </a>
```

For each div.